# How can I find a specific file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am new to this service so if I make a mistake please tell me.

I am fairly new to Python and have some ideas on projects I want to start. One of these projects includes the process of looking in a file in a specific folder and being able to write, read or delete it.

I want to a make program that allows the user to enter a password and be able to access, print to screen, create, edit, delete text files. Said text files could contain information such as passwords or profiles of people or just dirarie entered. To be able to print, delete and edit files  I need the program to be able to match and locate a file within a specific folder to the file (file name) the user inputed. The folder in question would be the folder the actual program is saved in because that is the default location where they are saved and at my level that's all I can do/program at the minute.

I am using the version 3.5.2 of Python and would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this problem...

Sincerely Isaac,

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a servicing site .please show what have you tried and ask a specific question

Comment: I have not yet tried an answer of my own because I am completely new to the process of file locating/finding and have no idea where to even start.

Comment: did you do google search? you will hundreds if not thousands of answer/resources for you problem

Comment: I would start by Googling for "python read from file", reading what I find, and trying to implement it myself. If and when I encountered a specific error I would research that and if I had confusion then I would ask a specific question about a specific error in a specific line of code here on this website.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the inconvenience as I said I am new to how the site works. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Start working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples and reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) relavent to those examples.  Pretty soon you will start to get ideas for solving your problem.  Try some of those ideas out.  If you get stuck, come back and ask questions: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To start things off, I'm going to assume that you have the most basic required knowledge of python. And I'd also like to preface my answer by recommending that you at least try and google what you would like to do before asking on stackoverflow.

That being said, the following is an excellent resource for what you would like to accomplish: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

As stated in the resource I've linked, to open a file you need to know the path of the file you would like to access.

Lets say that the path of your text file is C:\users\user\sampletext.txt

For simplicity, associate the required path with a variable:

```
path = 'C:\users\user\sampletext.txt'
```

To open a file you need to use python's built in open function. This function takes two parameters, the file you would like to access and the mode which you would like to access it in. You can read more about access modes in the resource which I have linked.

Since you want to to read and write the mode which you should specify is r+.

```
file = open(path, 'r+')
```

If you want to remove a file, at the top of your script you need to import the os library.

```
import os
```

To delete said file just use the file path which you already specified:

```
os.remove(path)
```

Again, I just want to reiterate that resources like these are very easy to find and it is beneficial to your learning if you try and find these on your own first. It isn't too hard.

Good luck with your project.